# Getting POST http://localhost:8080/boc/public/searchActivity 405 (Method Not Allowed) when sending ajax request in laravel5.3 using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am sending ajax request in laravel5.3 as shown in the code below:

```
function kpiFilter(id)
  {
    var view_url='{{route('search_activity.searchKPI')}}';
     $.ajax({
        url: view_url,
        type:'GET', 
        data: {"id":id}, 
        success: function(result){
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
  }
```

This is route:

```
Route::get('searchKPI',['as'=>'search_activity.searchKPI','uses'=>'KPIController@searchKPI']);
```

I am having type as GET but I received error as shown in the screen shot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqO60.png)

This is my controller:

```
 public function searchKPI($id)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
        $id = $request->id;
        return response()->json($id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The route you defined is not having parameter to get id.

However, Just change your controller to

```
public function searchKPI()
    {
        echo $_GET['id'];
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I have mistakenly written the route. I have updated the question.